# How to update navigation params of tab once the component is loaded?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm using a `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` and it contains of three `tabs`:

**`Tab3Component.js`**

```
class Tab3Component extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            badgeCount: this.props.badgeCount,
        })
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        const badgeCount = navigation.getParam('badgeCount', null);
        return {
            tabBarIcon({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) {
                if (routeName === 'Tab3Component') {
                    return (
                        <View style={{ width: 24, height: 24, margin: 5}}>
                            <Image source={Icons.icon_tab3}
                                style={{
                                    width: 24,
                                    height: 24,
                                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                                    tintColor: tintColor
                                }} />
                            {
                                badgeCount != null && badgeCount > 0 && 
                                <Badge style={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    bottom: '50%',
                                    left: '50%',
                                }} size={20}>{badgeCount}</Badge>
                            }
                        </View>
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.badgeCount != this.props.badgeCount) {
            console.log(this.props.badgeCount)
            this.props.navigation.setParams({
                badgeCount: this.props.badgeCount, // Update the badgeCount once receive an update from the API.
            })

        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // .. some stuffs here
        badgeCount: state.badgeCount,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        //.. some stuffs here
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tab3Component);
```

**`MainComponent.js`**

```
const MaterialTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1: { screen: Tab1Component },
        Tab2: { screen: Tab2Component },
        Tab3: { screen: Tab3Component },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Tab1',
    }
);
const TabNavigator = createAppContainer(MaterialTabNavigator);

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
    //... some stuffs here
    render() {
        return(
            //.. some stuffs here
            <TabNavigator />
        );
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

`badgeCount` is updating the value when I clicked the `Tab3`. But my question is, how to update the value of `badgeCount` once the `MainComponent` is loaded and not just by clicking the `Tab3Component`?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. You can use redux hook `useSelector` to get badgeCount from redux state

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function BadgeIcon(props) {
  // connect you badgeCount then render it here
  const badgeCount = useSelector(state => state.badgeCount); // <-- get your badgeCount from redux state
  return (
    <View></View>
  )
}

const MaterialTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1: { screen: Tab1Component },
        Tab2: { screen: Tab2Component },
        Tab3: {
          screen: Tab3Component,
          navigationOptions: () => ({
            tabBarIcon: props => <BadgeIcon {...props} />,
          }),
        },
    },
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, how do I connect or pass the badgeCount to BadgeIcon?

Comment: Did you store it on redux state? You can pass it the way you pass to `Tab3Component`

Comment: Yes I stored it to redux state, but how? `<BadgeIcon {...props} count={this.props.badgeCount} />`? I'm I correct? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Since I am using a multiple reducer, what I did is to specify the exact state. eg. `useSelector(state => state.Tab3Reducer.badgeCount);`.  Thank you for your help.